# Alternating stroke width between path nodes

Tags: javascript, animation, svg

I've stumbled upon the IntelliJ site again recently and wondered - could you animate the stroke that they use in the background?

[image: The stroke IntelliJ has in its background]

Maybe not exactly like the one in the picture, but some sort of way to alternate the draw width between different nodes of a path? I've spent quite some time now trying to ask Google in all sorts of ways what I'm trying to accomplish here, without much success.

Sure - I may be able to implement this through some intense clip-pathing and JS, but is there really no other way to achieve similar behavior? Or have I just simply not found the right words to pass to Google and SO so far?

Comment: What does "animate the stroke" mean to you? [Talk about that in your post](/help/how-to-ask) because if there's something want to do, be precise about it, and ideally: show code that you already tried, even if it didn't get you the result you wanted.

Comment: As you mention in your question you will need to use clipPath but no JS. Imagine a very wide stroke klipped by the shape you need. Next you can animate the clipped stroke. Please take a look at this example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68837375/animate-svg-fill-shape-by-following-the-form/68837922#68837922